# UnexpectedRollbackException in a @Transactional class when method is marked with noRollbackFor a thrown exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, transactions

I have got a @Transactional marked class FooServiceImpl that needs to populate an object FooDetails with values obtained from another @Transactional class BarServiceImpl.

When trying to get values from the BarServiceImpl an Exception1 is thrown. I'd like to leave the FooDetails field whose setter threw the exception empty and catch the exception. All other fields must
remain populated even if some setter threw an exception.

Sadly, thats not the case because the transaction has been marked as rollback-only because of the Exception1 being thrown even though I explicitly marked the method as "noRollbackFor = Exception1.class" and caught the exception.

Why is that happening and how can i fix the code to populate all fields whose setters did not throw an Exception and leave empty those whose setters threw one. 
Here is the code that leads to the behaviour:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface TransactionalService {
    // The name of the service
    String value() default "";
}

public class FooDetails {
    private String fieldA;
    private String fieldB;

    // getters and setters
    ...
}

@TransactionalService 
public class BarServiceImpl implements BarService {
    @Override
    public String getFieldB() throws Exception1 {
        ...
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception2 e2) {
            ...
            throw new Exception1();
        } catch (Exception3 e3) {
            ...
            throw new Exception1();
        }
    }
}

@TransactionalService 
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {
    ...
    ...

    @Autowired BarService barService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(noRollbackFor = {Exception1.class, Exception2.class, Exception3.class})
    public FooDetails getFooDetails(Long fooId) {
        Foo foo = fooDao.get(fooId);
        if (foo == null) {
            return null;
        }

        FooDetails fooDetails = new FooDetails();

        // getAFooDetails() has no exceptions to throw => ok
        fooDetails.setFieldA(getAFooDetails());

        // barService.getFieldB() throws an Exception1 => results in 
        // "org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException:
        //           Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only" => all foo fields left empty
        try {
            fooDetails.setFieldB(barService.getFieldB());
        } catch (Exception1 e) {
            LOG.info(e.getMessage());
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the exception classes?

Comment: @InsertKnowledge there's nothing special. Just custom exceptions with custom error messages that extend Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are using two logical transaction scopes: an outer transaction scope (in FooServiceImpl ) and an inner transaction scope (in BarServiceImpl). Both belong to the same single physical Transaction.

Since you say Exception1 is a checked exception, throwing it never causes any rollback (until explicitly declared) in BarServiceImpl.
Catching it in FooServiceImpl also does not lead to any rollback.

Usually, an UnexpectedRollbackException will be thrown, if an inner transaction scope (here: your BarServiceImpl.getFieldB) triggers a rollback.
When the calling method of the outer transaction scope (here: your FooServiceImpl.getFooDetails) returns normally, Spring's AbstractPlatformTransactionManager will try a commit. This commit fails because someone else already marked it as 'rollbackOnly' (which was done by the inner transaction scope). Then it will throw a UnexpectedRollbackException back to the caller of FooServiceImpl.getFooDetails.

So, your BarServiceImpl.getFieldB must have somehow thrown an unchecked exception (different from Exception1)

OR

You are using the one single physical transaction somewhere else in code you did not show here, and this piece of code did trigger a rollback via a unchecked exception.